Questions regarding doubts/ waswasa should be off-topic
Questions that are asked just to clear doubts or “wasasa” should be off-topic, they are mostly non-productive and do not help a larger audience.
This should add to or Improve the off-topic closure reasons
These questions are asked often:

is my prayer valid in this situation?
While performing wudu, some individuals often experience doubts about whether they recited Bismillah or completed specific steps correctly
What should I do to get rid of waswasa
Is My Salah Accepted or Not?

All of these questions have a problem; that is they are very specific.
Usually these type of questions have this syntax :

Title: Having Doubts
Question: A long paragraph of personal experience causing doubt , is
my experience/ act valid ???

An alternative approach would be to make a generic question that would encompass all necessary details.
Example : Having doubts of “X” , how to deal with them .
Which could be added in Topics to which some reference questions could be useful
